# Storefront product title on hover option

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, frontend, storefront

I am using Storefront Galleria Child Theme.

The problem is that on my products page https://www.mangoblogger.com/services/ the product titles/price disappear at 768 px and only appear back on hover.

I would like them to show all the time and remove the hover effect altogether.

I managed to remove the hover effect in media queries but could not get the title to show on screens > 768 px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The titles are hidden because of an `opacity: 0` setting on the `g-product-title` class. You can override that behavior by adding this rule somewhere after your theme's CSS file gets loaded (either in a later CSS file or in a `<style>` tag):

```
@screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .site-main ul.products li.product .g-product-title {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

However, this will also make the "Add to Cart" button show up all the time, so if you don't desire that behavior, you can add a rule that makes the button show up on hover only:

```
@screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .site-main ul.products li.product .button {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .site-main ul.products li.product:hover .button {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

I personally think it looks better that way.

Comment: The first part of the code worked for me. Thank you! I will further edit the Product Title to make it look prettier. Removed the add to cart button for all screen sizes for now.